# Build titanium appcelerator blackberry project

Tags: blackberry, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

i have a blackberry project in titanium  appcelerator, to install it on my device i need to build it first, but i cant find any button that lets me build the project. Googling didnt help me at all.

thanks !!!

**EDIT:** 
plus i followed the Troubleshooting section in the first link provided by  Muhammad Zeeshan

Comment: Did you try these links, http://developer.appcelerator.com/doc/blackberry/getting-started-beta-preview and http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/BlackBerry+Support

Comment: yes ! both ! i cant even run i on the simulator

Comment: Did you see `Starting the App` and `Installing To Device` in the first link?

Comment: i cant find the app in the downloads folder :S

Comment: no :S , im working on it, plus i think i have another version of titanium

Answer (score 0):

you need to have purchased at minimum a Indie account from appcelerator to have access to preview/beta software.

Comment: i have the indie account, but every time i try to install the project on my device i get error. plus if i only wat to build my project how i can do it?

Comment: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/125856/cannot-install-bb-project-on-my-device